# Difference between package and plugin?

Tags: android, flutter, plugins

Difference between package and plugin? Easy and Basic??

Easy Answer which we can say in the interview . If someone ask!

Answer (score 0):

The simple easy answer to that question is:

A `package` contains only Dart code.
A `plugin` contains both  Dart code and Native code (kotlin/js/swift/...)

A `package` can use `plugins` if it wants to. It will still be qualified as a `package`.

Answer (score 0):

A plug-in is a type of package—the full name is a plug-in package, and it is generally referred to as a plug-in.

Packages:

At minimum, a `Dart` package is a directory containing a `pubspec` file. Additionally, packages can contain dependencies (listed in the `pubspec`), `Dart` libraries, applications, resources, tests, images, and samples. The pub.dev website lists many packages—developed by Google engineers and generous members of the Flutter and Dart communities—that you can use in your applications.

Plugins:

A plugin package is a special package that enables an application to use platform features. Plugin packages can be written for Android (using `Kotlin` or `Java`), iOS (using `Swift` or `Objective-C`), web, macOS, Windows, Linux, or any combination thereof. For example, a plugin might provide a Flutter app with the ability to use the device's camera.